# How to Set Tweet Text Programmatically

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'd like to set the tweet text programmatically when using TwitterKit Tweet Composer. I could not find any method how to do that. I'm using the following code:

```
final Intent intent = new ComposerActivity.Builder(getActivity())
.session(session)
.createIntent();
startActivity(intent);
```

How can I set the tweet text programmatically? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For construction the tweet;

```
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.TweetComposer;
...

Uri myImageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/path/to/image"));

TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(this)
     .text("just setting up my Fabric.")
     .image(myImageUri);
builder.show();
```

You should better check this link https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/compose-tweets.html#twitterkit-tweet-composer

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use the intent since I will be displaying an app card. Any way to combine TweetComposer.Builder with ComposerActivity.Builder?